# How to authorize QuickBooks Online requests for a private desktop application

Tags: java, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I know there are other questions regarding this issue, but even after reading those, looking at the associated links and checking the QuickBooks docs, I'm struggling to understand it all and I feel like I'm going around in circles.

I need to create a load of invoices in my QuickBooks Online account based on data in Excel/CSV files. I will take a long time to do it manually (as well as being really tedious work) and I'll have to do it again in the future. I'm just trying to write a Java desktop application that will parse the file data and create the invoices in QuickBooks Online.

This is only for me and only for my companies QuickBooks account. I don't need my application to access other QuickBooks accounts, but I understand that I still need to go through the oAuth process (or do I?) to get the credentials that will allow me to make requests.

```
OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(
        accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);

ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(
        realmID, IntuitServicesType.QBD, oauthValidator);
```

I keep hearing that I have to register my app with Intuit to get the consumerKey and consumerSecret, but when I try to do that through developer.intuit.com, it's requiring an app URL and host name domain. This is a desktop app, I don't have those.

Is there seriously no way to simply access my QuickBooks Online account using the SDK by just supplying my userID and password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand that I still need to go through the oAuth process (or do I?)

Yes, you do.

> but when I try to do that through developer.intuit.com, it's requiring an app URL and host name domain.

Just enter in `localhost` to get through the registration process.

Then, you can use Intuit's OAuth Playground tool to get the access tokens you need, without having to actually implement any website-based stuff.

- https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

> Is there seriously no way to simply access my QuickBooks Online
>   account using the SDK by just supplying my userID and password?

There is no way to access your QuickBooks Online account programatically with just a username and password. You need to use OAuth.

It's really not that difficult if you just enter `localhost` in and use the Playground tool. Should take all of 30 minutes tops to get going.

Comment: I wish it only took 30 minutes. I've been going on this for about 2 days now and have gotten literally nowhere. The stuff generated in the playground tool doesn't work in any test application. It's a 403 bad request every time. There no way to specify localhost in that tool either and the token expires after 2 minutes. Do you have any samples in any language of an extremely basic user-interaction-free implementation of this just to get connected with correct tokens and credentials?

Comment: Follow the quick-start guide with the code here: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Comment: Any Working Examples for getting data of Quickbooks Online through JAVA